# Read an IIS log to pandas dataframe

Tags: iis, pandas

I have a IIS log file with lines in the following format :

> 61.245.163.59 - [16/May/2013:23:55:09 +0530] "GET /ehrm/Recruitment/Images/divider.gif HTTP/1.1" 404 1245
>   "http://www.example.com/ehrm/Recruitment/MyApplication.aspx?PRF_ID=000005&digest=6LL4BTSuW9YnE5R4T8k27Q" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT
>   6.1; rv:20.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0" GET /ehrm/Recruitment/Images/divider.gif - HTTP/1.1 www.example.com

I want get some columns from this and build a dataframe. In the following method it just build a dataframe with one column.  I want to have each of the splitting columns to be one column of the dataframe? And the other thing is the length of log file lines are not unique, so how to improve the accuracy of taking values by splitting like this?

```
log_list = []
for line in f:
    ip = (line.split(' ')[0])
    time = (line.split(' ')[2])
    method = (line.split(' ')[4])
    status = (line.split(' ')[7])
    bytes = (line.split(' ')[8])
    referrer = (line.split(' ')[9])
    agent = (line.split(' ')[10])
    data = ip + ' ' + time + ' ' + method + ' ' + status + ' ' + bytes + ' ' + referrer + ' ' + agent
    log_list.append(data)
df = pandas.DataFrame(log_list)
```

Comment: Have you tried the [read_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html#pandas-io-parsers-read-csv) function?  It may have some trouble with columns like the time, but you can combine those after.  By default, it should determine that the separator is a space but you can pass the argument `sep='\s+'` to be sure.

Comment: @TomAugspurger :  Thanks! Since I couldn't figure out a solution i wrote the splits to a separate file and then imported it as a dataframe.

Answer (score 5):

The following code should accomplish what you're trying to do:

```
from pandas import read_csv
log_file = 'filename.log'
df = read_csv(log_file, sep=r'\s+', usecols=[0, 2, 4, 7, 8, 9, 10])
```

[`read_csv` documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#csv-text-files).